# Angular 6 - How to download file from URL for both web and mobile version?

Tags: angular

I'm making a download function which can work on both web and mobile version of my app, using Angular. Here is my current download function:

```
export(status, id) {
    this.equipmentService.export(status, id).subscribe(data => {
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = 'Export data equipment.xlsx';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
}
```

The function worked perfectly on the web, but it wasn't working on the mobile version. I've tried using the same logic with an already nested `<a>` tag instead of creating a new one, but it wasn't working either.

Is there any way to perform the download for both web and mobile version?

I'm trying to avoid using third-party libraries and packages, but if that's the only way, then just shoot :) Thanks a lot!

Here is the element which actives the function:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="mat-menu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="editEquipment(row.Equipment_Id, $event, true)" *ngIf="isEditAvailable">
            <span>Edit</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="mark(1 , row.Equipment_Id)">
            <span>Mark Available</span>
        </button>

        <!-- Download button -->
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="export(2, row.Equipment_Id)" *ngIf="isViewDetailAvailable">
            <span>Export</span>
        </button>
        <!---->

        <button mat-menu-item (click)="deleteEquipment(row.Equipment_Id)" *ngIf="isEditAvailable">
            <span>Remove</span>
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
</td>
```